# How can I modify zlib MIN_MATCH value?

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I'm working with zlib 1.2.8 source code from http://zlib.net/
In the code, the minimum match value 'MIN_MATCH' is '3' (in zutil.h)

Now I want to modify that value from 3 to 4, so I modified the zutil.h

and there is a code in deflate.c

```
    /* Initialize the hash value now that we have some input: */
    if (s->lookahead + s->insert >= MIN_MATCH) {
        uInt str = s->strstart - s->insert;
        s->ins_h = s->window[str];
        UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[str + 1]);
#if MIN_MATCH != 3
        Call UPDATE_HASH() MIN_MATCH-3 more times
#endif
        while (s->insert) {
            UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[str + MIN_MATCH-1]);
#ifndef FASTEST
            s->prev[str & s->w_mask] = s->head[s->ins_h];
#endif
            s->head[s->ins_h] = (Pos)str;
            str++;
            s->insert--;
            if (s->lookahead + s->insert < MIN_MATCH)
                break;
        }
    }
```

and

```
            s->strstart += s->match_length;
            s->match_length = 0;
            s->ins_h = s->window[s->strstart];
            UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[s->strstart+1]);
#if MIN_MATCH != 3
            Call UPDATE_HASH() MIN_MATCH-3 more times
#endif
            /* If lookahead < MIN_MATCH, ins_h is garbage, but it does not
             * matter since it will be recomputed at next deflate call.
             */
```

so I modified the code like below

```
    /* Initialize the hash value now that we have some input: */
    if (s->lookahead + s->insert >= MIN_MATCH) {
        uInt str = s->strstart - s->insert;
        s->ins_h = s->window[str];
        UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[str + 1]);
#if MIN_MATCH != 3
        //Call UPDATE_HASH() MIN_MATCH-3 more times
        UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[str + 1]);
#endif
        while (s->insert) {
            UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[str + MIN_MATCH-1]);
#ifndef FASTEST
            s->prev[str & s->w_mask] = s->head[s->ins_h];
#endif
            s->head[s->ins_h] = (Pos)str;
            str++;
            s->insert--;
            if (s->lookahead + s->insert < MIN_MATCH)
                break;
        }
    }
```

and

```
            s->strstart += s->match_length;
            s->match_length = 0;
            s->ins_h = s->window[s->strstart];
            UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[s->strstart+1]);
#if MIN_MATCH != 3
            //Call UPDATE_HASH() MIN_MATCH-3 more times
            UPDATE_HASH(s, s->ins_h, s->window[s->strstart+1]);
#endif
            /* If lookahead < MIN_MATCH, ins_h is garbage, but it does not
             * matter since it will be recomputed at next deflate call.
             */
```

(I put the UPDATE_HASH() function under the 'if MIN_MATCH != 3' line)

and I compile, run the 'minigzip' test program with The Canterbury Corpus benchmark file

compress works without error, but decompress not working with 'incorrect data check' error message

How should I modify the code?
Anybody have idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MIN_MATCH` of 3 is built deeply into the code, so the one comment about repeating an update doesn't represent all the changes that would be required.  You would have to read and understand the algorithms used, make a fair number of changes, and then test them extensively to make sure you did it right.

If all you're trying to do is emit a literal instead of a match of 3, then you could change `if (s->match_length >= MIN_MATCH)` to `if (s->match_length >= 4)`.